# How to run a .bin on macosx

Tags: terminal

I've tried using the following commands to run my .bin file I have saved on my desktop. I'm able to navigate and run it using;

```
cd desktop
chmod +x ./two1.bin
./two1.bin
```

(`two1.bin` being the name of the file)

When it runs it displays each line in the terminal window and says "command not found" after it reads the first instruction on each line. It looks like this,

```
./two1.bin: line 1: 0010000000001001: command not found
./two1.bin: line 2: 0010001000001001: command not found
./two1.bin: line 3: 0010010000001001: command not found
```

Anyone have an idea on what I'm doing wrong? I've tried researching this online can't find the correct solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of file is this?

Comment: A binary file. contains all 1's and 0's.

Comment: According to your error messages it looks like ascii.

Comment: according to your description, the terminal seems to really be executing the binary but inside of it, if find a command that is not found hence the error message. You must post what your bin is  suppose to execute

Comment: Yeah you're right because it seems like it's trying to run the contents of the .bin as instructions within terminal.